# Emacs cursor border hides the character

Tags: faces, terminal-emacs, cursor

Cursor does not show the bottom section such as `_` or bottom part of character `g`. This is the case in `emacs -q -nw file.py` and also the case in my init.el file. I am not sure how can I fix this issue.

```
_g
_g
```

[image]

[image]

I am using `emacs` under iTerm, where it has smart-box setting it on. Smart-box should let cursor's color as: character's color to be the background color and character's color to be black.

[image]

---

Sometimes cursor's background and foreground color becomes the same, where I don't know how that happens

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you tried a different font? The cursor shape is likely not easy to change, but the font should be.
2. You can also increase line spacing: See [(elisp) Layout Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Layout-Parameters.html) and [(elisp) Special Properties](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html).
3. You can also try to change frame parameter `cursor-type` or user option `cursor-type`. (They allow the same values.) You can set the height of the cursor with them. But I don't know whether that will override what iTerm imposes.

Comment: From `Customize Face` => `Cursor` I tried to change its color and height but it does not apply :(

Comment: You have to change font in iTerm's setting not in Emacs

Comment: Ah in iTerm I have `font 11 , v|i 80 and n/n 80` will play and and see will make a difference

Comment: @Drew is there any default height value ? can we also make a change within init.el and play around to see which height value could be the best

Comment: Default in what way? Each font has a height. You can experiment by changing the `font` frame parameter (among other ways).

Comment: Can I also play around with `cursor-type` ? Due to iTerm2 i think all font's has a font size as 11 so it seems fixed

Comment: No idea - try. I added tag `terminal-mode`, as it seems you're not using GUI Emacs. I'm surprised that you can't change the font size at all in your terminals, however.